# Can you change the state of a button or checkbox in Android?

Tags: android

I need to edit some information read from a file. I need to restore the answers to questions to their original button and checkbox states.

I have looked at toggle() and setChecked but can't find any examples of how to use them.

Am I looking in the right place and do you have any sample code?

Comment: I mean, have you tried them? Like, yourCheckBox.setChecked(true)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBoxId).setChecked(true);
```

And if you would like to unset you could use

```
(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBoxId).setChecked(false);
```

You only need to fill in your id.
I hope that solves the problem.

Comment: I tried exactly that but I get that setChecked "cannot resolve method".  There is an import statement for the Checkbox widget.

Comment: could you provide us the layout code and the programm code?

Comment: what was the solution?